# Prove that a sequence converges iff that same sequence, minus the first m elements, also converges

Tags: real-analysis

I am very unsure of where to start this proof, and how it deviates from the simple proof that $x_{n}$ converges? Would somebody be able to set me on the right path?

Additionally, is this statement equivalent to saying "a sequence converges iff it has a convergent subsequence"?

Comment: Do you mean that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty }x_n$ exists iff $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty }x_{n+m}$ exists? If so Hint: use substitution

Comment: $(-1)^n$ has a convergent subsequence but does not converge.

Comment: @DavidP Did you even read the question?

Comment: @K.defaoite did you? this was a comment on OP's second question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This statement is saying that a sequence converges iff the sequence obtained by removing the first $m$ terms also converges.

$(\Rightarrow)$ Use the fact that a subsequence of a convergent sequence is also convergent and converges to the same limit.

$(\Leftarrow)$ Say $(x_{n+m})$ converges to $x$. Let $\epsilon > 0$. There exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|x_{n+m}-x| < \epsilon$ for all $n+m \geq N$. Use this to find an $M \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|x_n - x| < \epsilon$ for all $n \geq M$.

Note, the iff statement you wrote at the end is not true. The sequence $(1,-1,1,-1,...)$ has a convergent subsequence, but is not convergent itself.

Answer (score 0):

Assume $x_n \to L$, we show $x_{n+m} \to L,\forall m \ge 1$. Let $\epsilon > 0$ be arbitrary, $\exists N \ge 1$ such that: $|x_{n+m} - x_n| < \dfrac{\epsilon}{2}, |x_n - L| < \dfrac{\epsilon}{2}, n \ge N\implies |x_{n+m} - L| < |x_{n+m} - x_n|+|x_n - L| < \dfrac{\epsilon}{2}+\dfrac{\epsilon}{2} = \epsilon\implies x_{n+m} \to L$.
For the other direction, if $x_{n+m} \to L$, we show $x_n \to L$. Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given, $\exists N \ge 1$ such that if $n+m \ge N$ then $|x_{n+m} - L| < \epsilon$. Now let $N_1 = N + m$, then if $n \ge N_1\implies n - m \ge N\implies (n-m)+m \ge N+m > N \implies |x_{(n-m)+m} - L|< \epsilon\implies |x_n - L| <\epsilon\implies x_n \to L$.